# A/B testing and Predictive modelling - Subscription models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictive-models, modeling, ab-test, method-comparison

My problem is kind of a business case. I doing an analysis for an expiration plan. The current plan is 3 months, and the statistics are not so good. The conversion rate is on the decline, say 2%/month. I want to find out what happens if we are to change it to 4 months or 6 months,... which is better.

This sounds like an A/B testing case but my problem is the time in order to collect the data. Then, 2 groups of users may raise their complaints about the inconsistent change. Plus, it's very costly for the business for such experiments. I then decide to look for a predictive model to predict some of the key metrics where I can tweak some of the assumptions and compare the returns.
For example, with the 4-month plan, I would assume that there is a 1% decline/month instead of 2%/month.

I'm not sure if my approach is correct or not and how would I generate the data for my assumption. Any advice from your experience?

Comment: This is a business question not a statistics question. IMO you should just offer the plans openly and allow to choose. then there is no inconsistency etc and you can gather as much statistics as you want before deciding to close the others based on conversion etc.(O reilly seemed to do this and previously offered 6 month and 12 month subscription, now only 12)

Comment: My question is not limited to subscription plans though. For example, in mobile games/ marketing, we would offer free trials/ free coins/ coupons with some certain expiration in hope that our conversion rate would increase. Then the actual testing for months in order to gather data would cost businesses quite a lot and users will always want the longer expiration plan. I agree with you that this is a business question but still want to look for a statistical approach to this problem.